# Calling server side function that runs in the background of my website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I want to call a server side function which will run in the background of my website (while the user is navigating between the pages and continues to work normally).

I thought of writing the method in my Main.Master.cs page, call it from the client side of the content page, and display a popup at the end of the execution.

Is it possible?
How can I call Main.Master.cs method from content page client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
I used `jQuery ajax` with `generic http handler` returing `json`
I created handler and put my business logic there.
It return me the result in form of `json`
I iterated the `json` using jquery.
And created my html form that.

### Edit 1

Here are some useful links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/11/sp2010-ajax-part-4-returning-json-from.html

### Edit 2

You can also take benefit of jtemplate If you want to display something from the server to the page.
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/05/using-the-jtemplate-jquery-plugin-with-ajax-and-asp-net/

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you are using Ajax in your application.

here is a detailed article on how to do this.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109